# How to change website hyperlink image

Tags: facebook, image, hyperlink, favicon

I'm trying to change my website hyperlink image. For example, when I share the website on facebook, it appears a image related to the link (I want to change it).

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- maybe some link/href in here -->
</head>
[…]
</html>
```

[image: Here's an example]

Comment: Where can I find it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this icon link in your `<head>` tag.

```
<head>
    <link rel="icon" sizes="128x128" href="path/to/my/icon_128.png">
</head>
```

Comment: That is used to change the Favicons, right?
I'm trying to change the hyperlink image.

Comment: @JoãoGuerreiro: I'm not sure what you mean by "hyperlink image." If you could describe that better I might be able to give you a better answer. An image that serves as a hyperlink (if that's what you mean) is done by `<a href="example.com"><img src="path/to/image.png"></a>`. If that's not what you mean, please describe ***hyperlink image*** in more detail.

Comment: I added an example on my 1st post.
When I share my website on facebook, it picks a random image from it as a hyperlink, and I want it to show a specific image. How can I change it?
Thank you